# How do I "unpair" two regressors from one another that are from a common subject in a linear mixed-effects model?

Tags: r, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis

I'm building a linear mixed-effects model, and I'm not sure how to best structure my data. I was forced to collapse the response variable for each of the three conditions, so I am not even sure that it is possible to do what I'd like. Details below.

I have 6 conditions (0, 20, and 30%, each @ X3=0 or 1), and I effectively have 1 response/condition/subject. Let's call this Y.

I have 3 predictors, but for each of these predictor variables, I have 6 trials/condition/subject. However, two of the predictors are not necessarily "paired"; that is, they were collected at different times (both different from one another and at a different time than Y), but under the same conditions. Let's call X1 and X2 the "unpaired" variables and X3 the variable that is paired with both X1 and X2.

Ideally, my model would look something like:
Y ~ X1 + X2*X3 + (X1 + X2*X3 | subject)

However, I do not know how to effectively structure my data so that X1 and X2 become "unpaired". Is this possible? If so, how can I structure my data in R to do this? I'd rather not average X1 and X2 if I don't have to, but I am starting to think that this is my only option.

Thank you!

**** EDIT FOR CLARITY ****

This problem can be simplified if we get rid of X3. It will also be easier if we consider the data in the following format, which repeats for each subject:

```
subject    Y    X1      X2
1          Y1   X1_1_1  NA
1          Y1   X1_1_2  NA
1          Y1   X1_1_3  NA
1          Y1   X1_1_4  NA
1          Y1   X1_1_5  NA
1          Y1   X1_1_6  NA
1          Y1   NA      X2_1_1
1          Y1   NA      X2_1_2
1          Y1   NA      X2_1_3
1          Y1   NA      X2_1_4
1          Y1   NA      X2_1_5
1          Y1   NA      X2_1_6
1          Y2   X1_2_1  NA
1          Y2   X1_2_2  NA
1          Y2   X1_2_3  NA
1          Y2   X1_2_4  NA
1          Y2   X1_2_5  NA
1          Y2   X1_2_6  NA
1          Y2   NA      X2_2_1
1          Y2   NA      X2_2_2
1          Y2   NA      X2_2_3
1          Y2   NA      X2_2_4
1          Y2   NA      X2_2_5
1          Y2   NA      X2_2_6
1          Y3   X1_3_1  NA
1          Y3   X1_3_2  NA
1          Y3   X1_3_3  NA
1          Y3   X1_3_4  NA
1          Y3   X1_3_5  NA
1          Y3   X1_3_6  NA
1          Y3   NA      X2_3_1
1          Y3   NA      X2_3_2
1          Y3   NA      X2_3_3
1          Y3   NA      X2_3_4
1          Y3   NA      X2_3_5
1          Y3   NA      X2_3_6
```

This is what I mean by "unpaired" – $X1_{ij}$ and $X2_{ij}$ do not correspond with one another because they are measured during different trials. I could aggregate them (mean over $j$) to get $X1_i$ and $X2_i$ for a given $Y_i$, but then I lose out on a lot of information about uncertainty. I am not even sure that regression is the best approach.

Another approach that I'd considered is permuting all combinations of $X1_{ij}$ and $X2_{ij}$ to get a "point cloud" around each $Y_i$, but I am also unsure if this approach is valid, or even best.

I hope this clarifies!

Comment: Perhaps one approach I could take is permuting X1 & X2 to create all combinations of the two, which would give me a spread for each Y? I.e., for each Y, I would have 6! = 720 rows, each with a unique combination of X1 and X2. I am just unsure if this is valid, though.

Comment: What do you mean by "paired"?  You say that X1 and X2 are "unpaired" but also that X3 is "paired" with both.  If X1 is paired with X3, and X3 is paired with X2, isn't X1 paired with X3?

Comment: Thanks for the response. X3 is a known, controlled state of the system, and X1 and X2 are measured during that state. Therefore, I know X3 is truly the case for a given X1 or X2, but I do not necessarily know that a given X1 is co-occurring with a given X2. There's small variability between trials for X1 and X2, so placing a given X1 and X2 in the same row is arbitrary. Does this make any more sense?

Comment: This is still quite unclear.  Please give a lot more detail about what was done and how. I don't understand what you mean by "paired" or "unpaired"; if you are talking about  pairing as in "paired t tests" then I can't imagine why you would want to undo it.

Comment: Hi @PeterFlom, I've attempted to clarify.

Comment: If they are on the same people, they are paired.  If they are not on the same people, then your whole spreadsheet is going to be a mess and I don't know if there is anything you can do.  Each row should be a person.  If some things are missing, that's fine.

Comment: @PeterFlom I do not mean unpaired from the subject, I mean unpaired from one another. That is, $X1_{ij}$ and $X2_{ij}$ do not necessarily "belong" together. Each person has numerous rows because there are several trials. However, because X1 and X2 are measured separately, I do not know how to merge X1 and X2 into a row.

Comment: So, for each subject, you have a series of trials.  How many trials are shown in the example data above?  Within each trial, you take a series of measurements, say, after every 1 unit of time.  In a given trial, you measure Y (once per trial?) and either X1 or X2 but not both?

Comment: @DanHicks That is correct. In the above example, I have 36 trials (12 for each Y). The Y1's, Y2's, and Y3's are identical between each one's respective trials. And yes, I measure _either_ X1 _or_ X2 in a given trial, but I cannot measure both simultaneously.

Comment: In that case, it seems like you should treat each measurement of Y as a single "trial" with 12 covariates (the X1s and X2s).  So in the example above, there are 3 trials for subject 1.  Depending on your background theory, it might make sense to do something like use an average of X1 to reduce 6 covariates to 1, or apply PCA for dimension reduction.